# How to write the unit test case for the Classes which are annotated with @Configuration in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spock, spring-boot-test

I have a **Configuration Class**, which creates the bean for `RedissonClient` and also Creates the `CacheManager`. How to create the Unit Test case for this Configuration classes.

1. Can we write unit test case for `@Configuration` Class?
2. If we can, How we need to develop.

I prefer to write the test case in Spock Framework, with Groovy. If not, using Junit or Mockito Framework. How to write the unit test case for the Classes which are annotated with `@Configuration` in Spring Boot application

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {
    private static final String CONFIG= "Configuration";

    @Value("${redis.server.url}")
    private String redisUrl;

    @Value("${redis.server.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean 
    public RedissonClient redissonClient() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress(redisUrl).setPassword(password);
        RedissonClient client = Redisson.create(config);
        return client;
    }
    @Bean
    public CacheManager redissonCacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) {
        Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<String, CacheConfig>();
        config.put(CONFIG, new CacheConfig(24*60*1000, 12*60*1000));
        return new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient, config);
    }

}
```

Comment: Testing them in isolation doesn't make real sense, as they only have meaning inside a Spring application.

Comment: Yes. I agree, assume we build up the a application with other logics, then how do we need to ensure the classes which are annotated with @Configuration are covered.

Comment: You can unit-test it like any other class, i.e. by calling its public methods and verifying the results, e.g. that `redissonClient()` actually returns a `RedissonClient` instance with the expected configuration. If you want to test e.g. the values of the private members, it will be an integration test which you can also easily write. But ask yourself if you really want to test your application or that the Spring container works.

Comment: @kriegaex Can you check my answer, and suggest my answer

Comment: @m-deinum :Can you check my answer, and suggest my answer –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should realize that classes annotated with `@Configuration` are not really java classes, or at least you should not treat them like this. I know it sound controversial, I'll explain...

So historically spring used XML configurations to declare beans.

In spring 2.5 I guess, they've introduced an annotation based method where you put annotations `@Component`/`@Service` on classes, put `@Autowired` wherever you want spring to inject dependencies, then spring starts, scans the classpath, detects the beans and starts the application context with these beans.

Then Spring 3.0 has introduced a Java Configuration way of doing *spring related configurations*:`@Configuration / @Bean` in a special class.

So you should view these configuration classes as a "substitution" to the methods I've described before

Now let me ask, do you think you should test and XML bean configuration on its own? Probably not...
Do you think you should test that class has annotation `@Component` on it and all the necessary dependencies are autowired (with reflection or whatever)? Probably not.

**So why you want to test the Java Config classes?**

Here is another argument that you might find interesting

I've said that these classes are solely for spring to resolve the beans and it internally runs them. But spring doesn't just "run" them - it creates run-time wrapper for them to overcome some technicalities. Here is an example of one such thing:

Lest assume we have three beans: A,B,C such as B and C depend on A.

```
class A {}

class B {
   private A a;
   public B(A a) {this.a = a;}
}

class C {
   private A a;
   public C(A a) {this.a = a;}
}
```

All beans are expected to be singletons so we define the configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig { 
   @Bean
   public A a() { return new A(); }

   @Bean
   public B b() { return new B(a()); }

   public C c() {return new C(a()); }

}
```

Note that we call `a()` in definitions of `B` and `C`
Now, let me ask you a question: If its a "regular" java code how two different invocations of method `a()` (in B's and C's constructor) respectively are supposed to return *the same instance* of `A`?

So spring indeed uses a lot of sophisticated code and *this is what actually runs in runtime*, not your class as is, but the transformed version of it and you never know what are those transformations exactly since its and internal spring thing. But is so **what is the point of testing it as it is?**

I believe there are more arguments like this, but the point is clear - don't test the Configuration classes on their own.

Instead you can use an integration test that will run the spring container and load all the classes required in the configuration. However, in this case you'll probably want to mock some classes (by using `@MockBean` for example) so it won't be a 100% accurate test.

In terms of code coverage - IMO you should exclude these classes from coverage altogether

Comment: : Thanks for the info, which is very informative. But I do see some people develop the Groovy Test Case in which they spin up the spring application. Like you said   
**integration test that will run the spring container**, if I have to do for the above configuration they how I have to do. I'm totally new to this.

Comment: Spock is a junit built on tip of junit4. So you can integrate it with spring boot test like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-spock-testing

Comment: Can you check my answer, and suggest my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and found that, we can run the embedded redis server and we can check whether we able to connect to redis server by spin up the application. I don't if this is correct or not. But by doing so, it really takes time to complete it, took around 20 seconds. Used following dependency to test this // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.ozimov/embedded-redis
testCompile group: 'it.ozimov', name: 'embedded-redis', version: '0.7.2'

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [TestApp])
class CacheConfigurationSpec extends Specification {

@Shared
RedisServer redisServer;

def setupSpec() {
    redisServer = RedisServer.builder()
            .port(6379)
            .setting("bind 127.0.0.1")
            .setting("maxmemory 128M")
            .build()
    redisServer.start()
}

def cleanupSpec() {
    if (redisServer != null) {
        redisServer.stop()
    }
}

@Autowired
private RedissonClient redissonClient;

def "load all contexts"() {

}
}
@SpringBootApplication
class TestApp {
 static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args)
 }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to specify `classes=[TestApp]` in `@SpringBootTest` if you do it - specify a configuration with registered beans, it will load only that configuration, and the test will run much faster. Otherwise it tries to mimic startup of the whole application. All-in-all its a very complicated topic with a lot of facilities. If you want to really understand how it works I can recommend this session: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpz6b8ZEgcU   Also notice, that configuration can be cacheable so that if you have many test classes spring can cache app. context and greatly reduce time